# Gradle - Different JDK Version for Source and Test

Tags: java, maven, gradle

How can I configure Gradle to compile test classes for a different Java version than source classes?

I'm writing a project for Java 1.7, and I want to use Java 1.8 in my tests so I can use Lambda Behave. [In Maven this is pretty straightforward](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Compile+and+Test+with+Different+JDK+Versions), but I can't see how to achieve the same result in Gradle.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Of course, immediately after posting the question I stumble across the answer!

```
apply plugin: "java"

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
}

compileTestJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is often the case! I did want to know as well, so +1 to you

Comment: @EngineerBetter, do you know how to do this with Android?

Comment: Afraid not, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html):

```
plugins {
    `java`
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

tasks {
    compileTestJava {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}
```